# hide span with validator asp.net

Tags: .net, asp.net

Is it possible to completely hide css validator ? Despite its not visible as a text, there is visible space for it. In html there is simply a span with visibility hidden but it takes space:

Situation after adding requiredFieldValidator is shown below:

http://imageshack.us/g/571/desirez.png/

Thank You very much for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting the display property of the validator to dynamic. By default, it's set to static, which will render space for it on the page. If you set it it to dynamic, I'm quite certain it uses display:none to hide it completely.

Comment: Good answer. I only modified to improve the clarity a little bit.